# JavaScript (JQuery): Cancelling a selection in select control in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

In my application, I have a list of `<select>` controls. Change of selection in each of these controls can be made *only* after user confirmation. So I deal with it as follows:

```
<select onchange="changeSelect(this)" onmousedown="clickSelect(this)">
    <option value="1" selected="true">A</option> // here is 'default' value 1
    <option value="2" >B</option>
</select>

<select onchange="changeSelect(this)" onmousedown="clickSelect(this)">
    <option value="1" >A</option>
    <option value="2" selected="true">B</option> // here is 'default' value 2
</select>

// more select controls with arbitrary 'default' values, they can be added and removed dynamically
```

When the user clicks the select to choose another option, the `clickSelect(this)` method saves the currently chosen (old) selection:

```
function clickSelect(select) {
    globalScope.previouslySelected = $(select).val();
}
```

And now, if the user really tries to change the selection, I ask the user for confirmation, and if she does not confirm, I use the saved value to restore the previous state:

```
function changeSelect(select) {
    var response = confirm("Current changes to the threat log will be lost. Continue anyway?");
        if (response == false) {
            // change it back
            $(select).val(globalScope.previouslySelected);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, on IE, Chrome and Opera it works just fine. However, when I use Firefox, it does not work. THe reason is that FF calls the `onmousedown` handler twice during the selection -- first time when the user clicks to roll down the select control, and second time when she selects a new selection. Therefore the last remembered value of `globalScope.previouslySelected` will become the new selected value and not really the old one, as in other browsers.

I know using global variables is considered bad practice. This is not the issue here. Using any other storage will not make it work.

My only idea right now is to write a Firefox specific piece of code in the `clickSelect(select)` handler and ignore the second notification. However, for some reason the following code I found on stack overflow does not work:

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
     console.log("Olalala");
}
```

E.g., in Chrome it throws following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined
```

So how can I make it work so that ti would only run in FF? Or if any of you guys have a better solution to the problem of confirmation, I would gladly hear it. Just remember, there is a dynamic set of select controls, not just a single one. It has to work for all of them. Plus they can be added or removed dynamically, so in a single page request their number can vary. User loads page with a single select control, presses a '+' button and adds another select control, etc., but the solution has to work uniformly with all the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you're saving the currently selected option using the onmousedown listener? You can just initialize your global variable to hold the default option, and update it whenever a new selection is made.

Something like this:

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="changeSelect(this)">
    <option value="1" >A</option>
    <option value="2" >B</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var globalScope = {previouslySelected: $("#mySelect").val()};
function changeSelect(select) {
    var response = confirm("Current changes to the threat log will be lost. Continue anyway?");
    if (response == false) {
        // change it back
        $(select).val(globalScope.previouslySelected);
        return;
    }

    globalScope.previouslySelected = $(select).val();
}
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that on Firefox, the second mousedown event's target is the option, so you can use the following code to ignore the event in this case:

```
$("select").mousedown(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('option'))
        return;

    globalScope.previouslySelected = $(this).val();
});
```

With this code you can remove the `onmousedown` registration from your DOM.

Comment: Sounds right to me. You can do it all from the onChange event.

Comment: No. There is no single default option for all the select controls. First control can start with value 1, second with value 2, etc. Having a variable for each select control would result in a more complicated code. Gonna edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I can imagine that it could be done your way. However, if it is possible to just determine whether the code is running on FF, I think all I would need to do to my code would be to add few lines of code. Not a very robust solution, but working.

Comment: I really believe writing code to recognize and handle FF specifically is a bad idea. I edited my answer to include another solution that should work in all browsers and doesn't involve saving a variable for each select.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.